# Abrir una ventana (popup) en IE desde Chrome y obtener referencia a ella registrando un nuevo protocolo en Windows

Tags: javascript

Hemos conseguido abrir una ventana tipo popup usando javascript window.open(url,nombre,opciones) y registrando un nuevo 
manejador de protocolo ([Usamos esta solución en stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl) )

De esta forma funciona perfectamente todo, es decir, al crear un protocolo del tipo ie:
y ejecutar en chrome:

```
var miReferenciaalPopup = window.open('ie:http://www.google.com/', 'nombrePopup');
```

El popup se abre en IE desde crhome, pero hay dos comportamientos que necesitaría eliminar:

1) Se abre un popup previo al de IE en chrome con la URL completa, incluyendo el protocolo (ie:http://www.google.com/) Suponemos que es porque realmente es esa la que lanza el popup. Lo que hacemos es cerrarla desde javascript chrome una vez esta abre el popup en IE.

2) Perdemos la referencia en el javascript del chrome que abre el popup a la ventana popup que se abre en IE. Con lo cual ya no podemos reutilizarla para cargarle más contenidos. Realmente está en un navegador diferente al que la abre y quizás es por eso.

¿Se puede mejorar el punto 1, es decir, poder abrir el popup en IE directamente sin que se abra el popup intermedio en chrome?

¿Es posible obtener la referencia que deseamos en el punto 2, habría alguna forma de hacerlo?

Me sería de mucha ayuda cualquier luz, mejora o explicación de porque no es posible algo de esto.

Comment: Para el problema 1, puedes intentar detectar IE con feature detection, y bloquear la ejecución de la función que lanza el popup, si no lo es. Puedes usar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage para comunicar referencias entre las dos ventanas que ejecutan el programa.

Comment: Gracias nat por tu ayuda, ahora ya he conseguido, estando en chrome, abrir un popup en IE pero, ¿veis posible tener referencia desde el chrome a ese popup abierto en IE como para cerrarlo? Porque sin conseguir esto, ya todo lo demás no me vale.

Comment: 1. En principio el concepto de [sandbox](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aislamiento_de_procesos) te pueden complicar bastante la cosa, para el punto 1 habría que ver si `window.location` genera el comportamiento esperado, el punto 2 es insalvable tal como está planteado: la referencia es a una "ventana/pestaña" que existe en chrome e idealmente está aislada del resto del sistema u otras aplicaciones, el "popup" de internet explorer ya es otra aplicación.

Comment: 2. Tal vez si dieras mas detalles de cual es el objetivo o la funcionalidad esperada se puedan ver estrategias: sincronizar las ventanas desde un servidor, o escribir un manejador de protocolo real con comandos especificos (powershell) que mantenga la referencia al objeto/ventana ie.